# Create Highchart from the Following Data

Tags: javascript, highcharts

So I have two array values from which I want to create a Highcharts
The one array value is the String format and the other array value is of float type.

How can I create Highchart from the Following values at plottind data points at an interval of one second

X axis Value :

```
["2018-12-05 17:10:32", "2018-12-05 17:10:32", "2018-12-05 17:10:32", "2018-12-05 17:10:32", "2018-12-05 17:10:32", "2018-12-05 17:10:32", "2018-12-05 17:10:32", "2018-12-05 17:10:32", "2018-12-05 17:10:32", "2018-12-05 17:10:32", "2018-12-05 17:10:32","2018-12-05 17:10:33", "2018-12-05 17:10:33", "2018-12-05 17:10:33", "2018-12-05 17:10:33", "2018-12-05 17:10:33", "2018-12-05 17:10:33", "2018-12-05 17:10:33", "2018-12-05 17:10:33", "2018-12-05 17:10:33", "2018-12-05 17:10:33", "2018-12-05 17:10:33"]
```

Y Axis Value :

```
[1.2, 4.5, 3.5,4.5,6.7,2.6, 4.7,8.6,7.8,5.7,2.4,1.2, 4.5, 3.5,4.5,6.7,2.6, 4.7,8.6,7.8,5.7,2.4]
```

The Challenges are that I have same no of X-axis values for multiple X-axis as you can see above because multiple no. of data are recorded in single second time. and after some time it changes .
I want the data to be drawn in highcharts something like the following:

https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/yn7Lg09r/

Any Help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a **startPoint** feature to create this chart and **pointInterval** to 1000 which is equal one second. To get the 'live' effect use the **addPoint** feature.

**Demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/n5ufy1ga/

```
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime'
  },

  plotOptions: {
    series: {
      pointStart: Date.UTC(2018, 4, 12, 17, 10, 32),
      pointInterval: 1000 // one second = 1000 miliseconds
    }
  },

  series: [{
    data: [1.2, 4.5, 3.5, 4.5, 6.7, 2.6, 4.7, 8.6, 7.8, 5.7, 2.4, 1.2, 4.5, 3.5, 4.5, 6.7, 2.6, 4.7, 8.6, 7.8, 5.7, 2.4]
  }]
});

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    chart.series[0].addPoint(Math.random() * 10, true, true);
  }, 1000)()
})
```

---

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.line.pointStart

API addPoint: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#addPoint